# Action bar only shows one item next to search view

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

I want to have a search view and two buttons in the Action Bar. So I created menu/options_menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:title="Route"
    android:id="@+id/action_route"
    android:icon="@drawable/route"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:title="Cancel"
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    android:icon="@drawable/cancel"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

I am inflating it in code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return true;
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see, only the first item ("route") is shown.
I can make second item ("cancel") visible if I let iconify the search widget:

```
    //searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

[image]

However, I want to have search widget expanded and both items visible. Is it possible?

**Update**

I managed to make them visible by setting `android:orderInCategory="1"` for "Route" and "Cancel" and `android:orderInCategory="2"` for the search widget:

[image]

This is almost what I wanted. The issue is that I want search widget to go first (leftmost), and then these two items. Is it possible?

**Update 2**

I tried "recommended" way. I set for `SearchView`:

```
android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

After I click on search icon, I get expanded view:

[image]

Two problems:

1. (Minor) Navigation UI occupies a room on the left thus reducing space available for `SearchView`.
2. (Major) Android icon appears as a part of navigation UI. Can I get rid of it?

Comment: Understand this. The user will click the search button and they want to interact with the now expanded search widget. The don't care about anything else. They want to search. Any other button is just a distraction. Any buttons that are unrelated to task at hand can be hidden. This is a pseudo problem. Collapse the search button by default as shown here https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec Thanks for your comment. I tried what you suggest and updated my question. Can I remove the Android icon which appears on the left side of the action bar?

Comment: If you use Material or AppCompat theme (highly suggested) the navigation arrow closes the search view and the icon is gone. If you cannot use Material or AppCompat themes, call `getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(0));` to remove the icon.

Comment: @Nick my answer is working or not ?

Comment: @Nick my answer is helpful?

Comment: Your answer is the best one, so I award bounty to you. But the question how to have always expanded SearchView is still open.

Comment: @Nick thanks for bounty. You need open searchview?

Comment: @Nick check my answer. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Created one demo, check it :

**menu.xml :**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/searchview"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"/>

    <item
        android:title="Route"
        android:id="@+id/action_route"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item
        android:title="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**searchview.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**Java :**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        if(searchItem!=null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

**Edited Java Based on Requirement (Always open searchview) :**

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchItem.expandActionView();
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
        if(searchItem!=null) {
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
            searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
            // This listener use for handle back press if you want to go back without collapsing searchview
            MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                    onBackPressed();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
```

**Screenshots :**

[image: Without click] [image: With click]

Comment: `MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener` is deprecated. Is there any code to substitute it?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by setting a maximum width for the search view, equal to screen width, minus the action item width.

### res/menu/search.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_search"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_filter"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter_list_white_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_filter"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

### Activity or fragment:

```java
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setIconified(false);
    searchView.setMaxWidth(getSearchViewMaxWidth());
    searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onClose() {
            performSearch("");
            return true; // Disable dismissing the search view
        }
    });
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            performSearch(query);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

@Px
private int getSearchViewMaxWidth() {
    final int screenWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final int actionItemWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.action_item_width);
    return screenWidth - actionItemWidth;
}
```

### res/values/dimens.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- ... -->
    <dimen name="action_item_width">48dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `onCreateOptionsMenu` as follows to explicitly set the menu items visible when the `SearchView` menu item has focus.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);


    if (menu.getItem(0).isFocused()) //detect if search view has focus 
    {
        //explicitly set menu items visible
        menu.getItem(1).setVisible(true);
        menu.getItem(2).setVisible(true);
    }

    return true;    
}
```

Comment: it does not work for me. second item (cancel) is still not visible in portrait.

Answer (score 0):

you can customize width of expanded search view by this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.width=500;
        searchView.setLayoutParams(params);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).expandActionView();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

<item
    android:title="Route"
    android:id="@+id/action_route"
    android:icon="@drawable/route"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

<item
    android:title="Cancel"
    android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
    android:icon="@drawable/cancel"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```